# how to save PHPCPD output into text file

Tags: php, windows

I Installed the PHP Copy/Paste Detector (PHPCPD) to my project its working fine. I am getting big list so I couldn't able to view it clearly in windows comment prompt.

I would like to save this report to txt file. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the option --log-pmd that saves the output into an XML

You can run something like this:

phpcpd /dir/to/scan --log-pmd /output/dir/my_file.xml